# Simple/creative way to test this function without HW

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd

I was wondering if anyone would know of a simple way to test this function without the actual HW.  The trouble is that I set two registers and I want to read them back so that I can verify that the code is good.

```
void Class::setSomeRegister( uint8_t unit, uint8_t input )
{
if (input<=15)
    iHW.setBits( OFFSET, unit*4, 4, input );
iHW.setBit( OFFSET_TWO, unit, input==16 );
}
```

The register functions all have the form

```
void HW::setBits/setBit
{

readRegister()
//Modify
writeRegister()
}
```

In the read and write functions I have done this.

```
readRegister
{
#ifdef EMULATION
    return iTestRegister;
#else
     //Real Code
#endif
}

writeRegister( offset, const uint32_t value )
{
#ifdef EMULATION
    iTestRegister = value;
#else
    //Real Code
#endif
}

static uint32_t iTestRegister;
```

I have tried using std::stack too but that does not work as after pushing the value in the first setregister, I pop it in the second.  Any ideas how this can be handled simply.  I don't want to add too much logic to handle this, if that is possible.  Basically I am just looking for creative ideas.

Comment: Surely you just need an array to handle the max no of registers (two ?) ?

Comment: I have over 1000 registers, I could do that but is there a simple way?

Comment: maybe std::map<name,value>? name should be register name or an address, value should be uint32_t type. or maybe just use file as your memory, use offset as offset in the file.

Comment: @user1876942: the number doesn't really matter - you just need an array of some sort, so that you emulate the registers with a chunk of memory - I don't really see a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can ***use mocks*** for that. I recommend [***CppUTest***](http://cpputest.github.io/) - it's a *C/C++ unit testing framework* with *mock support* and memleak detector - but others like ***GoogleMock*** are an option too.

---

## Example

Here's a *small and basic* example for illustration (using CppUTest):
*(I'm using some C++11 features - just personal preference, not mandatory!)*

### HW-Interface

```
class HW
{
public:
    virtual void setBit(uint32_t offset, uint8_t unit, uint8_t bits) = 0;
    virtual void setBits(uint32_t offset, uint8_t whatever, uint8_t unit, uint8_t bits) =0;
};
```

### HW-Interface mock

```
class HWMock : public HW
{
public:
    void setBit(uint32_t offset, uint8_t unit, uint8_t bits) override
    {
        mock().actualCall("setBit")
                .withParameter("offset", offset)
                .withParameter("unit", unit)
                .withParameter("bits", bits);
    }

    void setBits(uint32_t offset, uint8_t whatever, uint8_t unit, uint8_t bits) override
    {
        mock().actualCall("setBits")
                .withParameter("offset", offset)
                .withParameter("whatever", whatever)
                .withParameter("unit", unit)
                .withParameter("bits", bits);
    }

};
```

### Some example implementation

```
class ExampleImpl
{
public:
    static const uint32_t OFFSET = 10;

    ~ExampleImpl()
    {
        delete hw;
    }

    // This method is under test
    void setSomeRegister(uint8_t unit, uint8_t input)
    {
        if( input >= 15 )
        {
            hw->setBits(OFFSET, unit * 4, unit, input);
        }
        else
        {
            hw->setBit(OFFSET, unit, input);
        }
    }

private:
    HW* hw = new HWMock;
};
```

### Unit Tests (with mocking)

```
TEST_GROUP(So26382638)
{
    void setup() override
    { 
        hw = new HWMock;
    }

    void teardown() override
    {
        mock().clear();
        delete hw;
    }

    HW* hw;
    ExampleImpl impl;
};


TEST(So26382638, setRegisterSetsBit)
{
    const uint8_t unit = 1;
    const uint8_t bits = 3;
    mock().expectOneCall("setBit")
            .withParameter("offset", ExampleImpl::OFFSET)
            .withParameter("unit", unit)
            .withParameter("bits", bits);
    impl.setSomeRegister(unit, bits);
    mock().checkExpectations();
}

TEST(So26382638, setRegisterSetsBitsIf15OrMore)
{
    const uint8_t unit = 1;
    const uint8_t bits = 17;
    mock().expectOneCall("setBits")
            .withParameter("offset", ExampleImpl::OFFSET)
            .withParameter("whatever", 4 * unit)
            .withParameter("unit", unit)
            .withParameter("bits", bits);
    impl.setSomeRegister(unit, bits);
    mock().checkExpectations();
}
```

In this (*improvable*) example there's a lot of static data, eg. unit = 1. You can easily pass any sort of data to your mock using `mock().setData(...)` / `mock().getData(...)`. You also can use many different mocks and named mocks. Check the manual for some good examples.

### Documentation

- [CppUTest](http://cpputest.github.io/index.html)

  - [Testing Manual](http://cpputest.github.io/manual.html)
  - [Mocking Manual](http://cpputest.github.io/mocking_manual.html)
- [GoogleMock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/)